# fetch value based on arguments passed to object

Tags: java, arrays

I have a scenario where i have to return the value based on the value passed in arguments. This is my code.

```
package p_java_works;
public class city_if {
    public String a, b, c, d, z;
    String Method1(String aa, String bb, String cc) {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;
        c = cc;
        d = "USA";
        if (c == d) {
            return a;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        city_if x = new city_if();
        String t = x.Method1("chris", "NY", "USA");

        city_if y = new city_if();
        String t1 = y.Method1("neil", "LND", "UK");
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(t1);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:
chris
null**

The output is returning NULL. I should get only the record that is from USA the other record here i.e UK should not be returned on the output screen.

Comment: Why do you think null should not be printed?
If `t1` is null, what do you expect will happen when you execute System.out.println(t1);

Comment: Just a side-note: You should really learn about code styling conventions/practices.

Comment: ya i don know what to give in the else part. thats y gave the some value as null.  Please provide an alerternative solution for my code.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing String with the `==` operator when you should be using the `.equals()` method.

`c` will ever only equal `cc` if they refer to the same String in memory.

Comment: even if i use the .equals i want the code to return the name that was passed. so for the record which is not equal it fetches a null and return it, which i dont want in the output. I jus want the members from USA.

Comment: Then you either need to restructure your code to achieve this @KannanRadhakrishnan or ask another question pertaining to this issue